# WHat is the best solution for large caching in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, api, caching, sinatra, jruby

I'm building an REST API in Ruby with JRuby+Sinatra running on top of Trinidad web server.

One of the functionalities of the API will be getting very large datasets from a database and storing them in a middle caching/non relational DB layer. This is for performing filter/sorting/actions on top of that dataset without having to rebuild it from the database.

We're looking into a good/the best solution for implementing this middle layer.

My thoughts:

- Using a non relational database like Riak to store the datasets and having a caching layer (like [Cache Money](https://github.com/ngmoco/cache-money)) on top.

Notes:

- Our datasets can be fairly large

Comment: This is a large, open-ended architecture question. There are many possible solutions. Choosing the best one requires more knowledge of the size and type of data, how it will be queried and updated, and specific performance requirements.

Comment: Hi Mark. We're talking about a Java backend (where JRuby comes into play) and we will be storing temporary data. This temporary data will have to be somewhat dynamic. It will be used to store user information (rather small in size) and big chunks of json formatted data. Unfortunately I'm not in liberty to talk about the real use case scenario. Could you please provide, in your opinion, the perfect solution for a normal app? Thank you and apologies for not being able to be more precise, I know it doesn't help.

Comment: Just to give an update. We decided to go with Redis and Ohm for the wrapper and so far is working perfectly for what we need. Might be useful for anyone else :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked for an opinion, I'll give you mine... I think MongoDB would be a good match for your needs:

http://www.mongodb.org/

I've used used it to store large, historical datasets for a couple of years now that just keep getting bigger and bigger, and it remains up to the task.  I haven't even needed to delve into "sharding" or some of the advanced features.

The reasons I think it would be appropriate for the application you describe are:

- It is an indexed, schemaless document store which means it can be very "dynamic" with fields being added or removed
- I've benchmarked it's performance versus some SQL databases for large "flat" data it performs orders of magnitude better in some cases.
- https://github.com/guyboertje/jmongo will let you access MongoDB from JRuby

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any experience comparing Mongodb and riak?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any experience with riak... but I have used several SQL DB's and CouchDB, which might be an option as well.